# Show/hide child components

Tags: angular

Imagine the following piece of HTML code which is the template of an Angular component:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <app-one></app-one>
  <app-two [someService]="someService"></app-two>
  <app-three></app-three>
  <button type="button"  (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
  <button type="button"  (click)="next()">Next</button>
</form>
```

What I want is not to show all the child components at once (UI will become too big) but one by one upon `Next` button click. At first, 
I want `<app-one>` to appear, then upon `Next` `<app-two>` to replace `<app-one>` and upon second `Next` click `<app-three>` to replace `<app-two>` and 
`Submit` button to replace `Next` button.
I can implement that by using `*ngIf` directives, however I am sure there must be a nicer way to do that (using `ng-template`, `ng-container`?).
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you pretend is something like a stepper, this [link](http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/#/pages/extra-components/stepper) will show you an example.

You can also create a variable to save the step the user are in.
For example:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
   <app-one *ngIf="step==1"></app-one>
   <app-two *ngIf="step==2" [someService]="someService"></app-two>
   <app-three *ngIf="step==3"></app-three>
   <button type="button"  (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
   <button type="button"  (click)="next()">Next</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct. *ngIf would increase cyclomatic complexity unnecessarily. Use ***ngSwitchCase**.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" [ngSwitch]="currentStep">
  <app-one *ngSwitchCase="step-1"></app-one>
  <app-two *ngSwitchCase="step-2" [someService]="someService"></app-two>
  <app-three *ngSwitchCase="step-3"></app-three>
  <button type="button"  (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
  <button type="button"  (click)="next()">Next</button>
</form>
```

The value of currentStep can be updated from next method

```
public next(): void {
// Default value of selectedStep being 1
currentStep = `step-${++this.selectedStep}`;
}
```